# How to import multiple .m files at once?

Tags: list-manipulation, packages

For example, I import several files with the following lines:

```
<< (NotebookDirectory[] <> "/psoPackage/psoGenericFunctions.m");
<< (NotebookDirectory[] <> "/psoPackage/calculateVelNiches.m");
<< (NotebookDirectory[] <> 
   "/objectiveFunctions/objective functions.m");
<< (NotebookDirectory[] <> "/psoPackage/bifurcationMainFunctions.m");
<< (NotebookDirectory[] <> "/objectiveFunctions/limiters.m");
<< (NotebookDirectory[] <> "/pseudoRandomGen/haltonSerie.m");
<< (NotebookDirectory[] <> "/Graphics/Graphics.m")
```

But I need to import the files in one line. For example:
create a new file .m  and include in this the package.
So only import this new file. Anyone have any ideas how to do this?

Comment: `Get[NotebookDirectory[] <> #] & /@ {firstFileName, secondFileName, ...}`? However, *why* do you need to get them all in one line? I can't see much advantage in that myself, and it seems to detract from overall readability.

Comment: This packages together are software. 
So i need only import a package containing all other

Answer (score 1):

Make a **load.m** file in the Notebook directory that has the lines:

```
<< "/psoPackage/psoGenericFunctions.m";
<< "/psoPackage/calculateVelNiches.m";
<< "/objectiveFunctions/objective functions.m";
<< "/psoPackage/bifurcationMainFunctions.m";
<< "/objectiveFunctions/limiters.m";
<< "/pseudoRandomGen/haltonSerie.m";
<< "/Graphics/Graphics.m"
```

In the notebook that is in the directory have the command:

```
<< (NotebookDirectory[] <> "load.m")
```

You may have to play around with the "/" marks depending upon your system.

Comment: It might be useful to do something like `FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], #}] & /@ FileNames["*.m"]` to get a list of full file paths.